# EWS: Set action is invalid for property when updating occurrence in a series

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using the EWS API 1.2.1 from Microsoft to communicate with Exchange Server 2007 SP1. When I try to update a specific occurence in a series I allways get the error: 'Set action is invalid for property'. The sample below creates a masterrecurrence which is succesfull then I bind to this masterrecurrence and try to update the 3rd sequence in the series. This fails...

```
this is the stack trace:

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException was unhandled
Message=Set action is invalid for property.
Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
StackTrace:
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.ThrowIfNecessary()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
```

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Below you find the complete testcode I have set up.

Thanks and best regards!

Dimitri

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace EWS_testWithRecurrences
{
    class Program
    {


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1,    TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
        string ls_master = string.Empty;

        // SSL - security (for accademius sake)
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            delegate(Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                return true;
            };

        _service.Url = new Uri("https://exchangeserver/EWS/exchange.asmx");
        _service.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");


        // Add master for accedemius sake
        Appointment app = new Appointment(_service);
        app.Subject = "Weekly on friday!";
        app.Start = new DateTime(2012, 7, 13, 10, 0,0);
        DayOfTheWeek[] days = new DayOfTheWeek [] { DayOfTheWeek.Friday };
        app.End = new DateTime(2012, 7, 13, 10, 0, 0).AddHours(2);
        app.Recurrence = new Recurrence.WeeklyPattern(app.Start.Date, 1, days);
        app.Recurrence.StartDate = app.Start.Date;
        app.Recurrence.NumberOfOccurrences = 10;
        // Save: works!
        app.Save();
        ls_master = app.Id.UniqueId;

        // Occurrence exception (bind to master) and change the 3rd series in the sequence
        Appointment occurrence = Appointment.BindToOccurrence(_service, new ItemId(ls_master),3);
        occurrence.Subject = "Urgent status update";
        occurrence.Start = new DateTime(2012, 7, 11, 14, 0, 0);
        occurrence.End = new DateTime(2012, 7, 11, 14, 0, 0).AddHours(2);
        occurrence.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
        // Save ==> this fails!
        occurrence.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a related "Modified occurrence is crossing or overlapping adjacent occurrence" error.

I think this is because the modified occurence start can't be set before the master recurrence start (2012-07-13 > 2012-07-11):

```
app.Start = new DateTime(2012, 7, 13, 10, 0,0);
...
occurrence.Start = new DateTime(2012, 7, 11, 14, 0, 0);
```

After changing that to:

```
occurrence.Start = occurrence.Start.AddHours(-6);
```

Everything seems to be working.

I think you should change appointment start first and then change the first occurence of it and delete the last one. But I'm not sure if you really want that. It would be a way easier to just add one nonrecurring appointment.